# Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range. The statement has 0 parameters."

Tags: android, mysql

I am struggling a lot to fix this issue. Can any one please help me to get through this. Please let me know where am I going wrong in my where clause in the query statement. I want to read values from all the columns and then give those to display.

Here is my query code:

```
public Task getTask1(String id) {


        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        String selection = SQLiteHelper.UID;

        String[] columns = { SQLiteHelper.UID,
                SQLiteHelper.TASK_NAME, SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS, SQLiteHelper.DESCRIPTION, SQLiteHelper.REMARKS, SQLiteHelper.DATETIME, SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME,
                SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME, SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_TIME};

        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
Cursor cursor = db.query(
        SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME,
        columns,                
        selection,              
        selectionArgs,          
        null,                   
        null,                   
        null                    
);

if (cursor != null) {

            cursor.moveToNext();


            task = new Task(
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                    cursor.getString(6), cursor. getString(7), cursor.getString(8));

            Log.d("Pana", "The value of Task is" + task);

        }


        return task;
    }
```

Updated method as per the suggestions:

```
public Task getTask1(String id) {


        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        String selection = SQLiteHelper.UID;

        String[] columns = { SQLiteHelper.UID,
                SQLiteHelper.TASK_NAME, SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS, SQLiteHelper.DESCRIPTION, SQLiteHelper.REMARKS, SQLiteHelper.DATETIME, SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME,
                SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME, SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_TIME};


        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, String.valueOf(id)};

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + " where _id = ?", selectionArgs);

//        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
//
//            task = new Task(
//                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
//                    cursor.getString(6), cursor. getString(7), cursor.getString(8));
//
//            Log.d("Pana", "The value of Task is" + task);
//
//            cursor.close();
//Don't forget to close your cursor, otherwise you will have a memory leak!

        if (cursor != null) {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                task = new Task(
                        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                        cursor.getString(6), cursor. getString(7), cursor.getString(8));

                Log.d("Pana", "The value of Task is" + task);
            }

            cursor.close();
        }


        return task;


        }
```

Here is my logcat:

```
 11:23:06.955    1142-1142/com.ms.t.tms D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
02-27 11:23:06.970    1142-1142/com.ms.t.tms E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ms.t.tms, PID: 1142
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ms.t.tms/com.ms.t.tms.EditScreen}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
            at com.ms.t.tms.SQLiteDataBaseAdapter.getTask1(SQLiteDataBaseAdapter.java:143)
            at com.ms.t.tms.EditScreen.onCreate(EditScreen.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I have total of 9 columns in one row including _id as the first column I am trying to query based on _id and I am ending up getting this error. Please help me. I am able to Insert records, Display the records as a list, Read details of the inserted records, but when I try to edit those records I am facing this problem. When I pass null to all the parameters I end up getting the first row of table always. Please provide suggestions. let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No I have many rows. I am able to view the detail of all rows but I am not able to go to the edit page. As soon as I select Edit I get this error..

Comment: take a look at my answer below using rawQuery instead of query, see if that helps.

Comment: It looks like you are only trying to return one row in this function, and in addition you are only querying one row.  So, no need for a while loop here.  Your cursor is only going to return one row if the where clause limits the query to one _id.

Comment: Yes exactly you are right. But why is my code giving errors?

Answer (score 4):

Your `selection` argument should be like

```
String selection = SQLiteHelper.UID + " = ?";
```

It needs a `?` to define a placeholder where SQLite will bind a value from `selectionArgs`.

---

You have mixed and matched your code picking snippets from both the answers available here. That won't work. Change the whole method to

```java
public Task getTask1(String id) {

    db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] columns = { SQLiteHelper.UID, SQLiteHelper.TASK_NAME,
            SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS, SQLiteHelper.DESCRIPTION,
            SQLiteHelper.REMARKS, SQLiteHelper.DATETIME,
            SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME,
            SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME, SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_TIME };

    String selection = SQLiteHelper.UID + " = ?"; // MISSING in your update!!
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { id };

    Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        task = new Task(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6),
                cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8));
        Log.d("Pana", "The value of Task is" + task);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return task;
}
```

Comment: Changed the code as per your suggestion I am getting the below exception after that:
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: The error means that because of the where clause the query has returned no records but you're still trying to read from it. Change your if condition as shown in my answer. Try again with a where clause value that returns some records.

Comment: The answer above? I used that and it gave index out of bounds. When I give null It reads all the columns but of only one row, so the problem is in my where query only right?

Comment: If you're expecting multiple records, use a `while` loop as shown in my answer.

Comment: Getting same error even tough I use a While loop.  Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range. The statement has 1 parameters.

Comment: Please update your question with the changes you've done to your code. It'll be easier to spot the problem again.

Comment: Updated the question with the updated method as per suggestions.

Comment: @Kesh1234 Is this method supposed to return multiple tasks or just one? Will there be multiple entries per user id?

Comment: I have a list view of Tasks like Task1, Task2, Task3... As I select an item such as Task5. I need a detail view of Task5 to be displayed. I am getting that. i have a button edit in detail page. When I select that the Edit view of Task5 should be displayed, I am not getting that.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
    public Task getTask1(String id) {


        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

        String selection = SQLiteHelper.UID;

        String[] columns = { SQLiteHelper.UID,
                SQLiteHelper.TASK_NAME, SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS, SQLiteHelper.DESCRIPTION, SQLiteHelper.REMARKS, SQLiteHelper.DATETIME, SQLiteHelper.ESTIMATED_COMPLETION_TIME,
                SQLiteHelper.ACTUAL_COMPLETION_TIME, SQLiteHelper.NOTIFY_TIME};


        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{id};

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME + "  where _id = ?", selectionArgs);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            task = new Task(
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                    cursor.getString(6), cursor. getString(7), cursor.getString(8));

            Log.d("Pana", "The value of Task is" + task);

        cursor.close(); //Don't forget to close your cursor, otherwise you will have a memory leak!
        }


        return task;
    }
```

Comment: Its giving me the below syntax error:
near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from ?  where _id = ?

Comment: I used my TableName in the place of ? for table name I got this error:
Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters. Can you please tell me how can I get rid of this and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, just realized that question marks can only go in the where clause.  See updated answer.  Also see documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Just realized that there is no reason to call String.valueOf() on the String id.  Take a look at the latest edit...

Comment: Yes, I am getting the list and detail. So It has to be there right? is there a way to check that other than this?